# Firebase Dynamic Links and custom URL schemes

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I would like to use a custom URL scheme (e.g. `myapp://`) for my Dynamic Links which are set up in Firebase. Would I need to set the `apn` (Android) and `ius` (iOS) Dynamic Link parameters to be `myapp` to make them work?